# Wifi hotspot with redirect to HTML

Tags: wifi, hotspot

I'm trying to create a wifi hotspot with my *Raspberry Pi B+* that redirects the connected devices to a specific HTML page, hosted on the Raspberry. I can create the hotspot following [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/overview) tutorial. Is there a way to force a HTML page load, like some routers do?

The plan is:

1. The user will connect to the Raspberry Pi wifi hotspot.
2. The user device will load a HTML page hosted on the Rasp.
3. The user will download files through the links on the HTML page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do that with `iptables`.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:80
```

This redirects all requests made via port 80 and 443 (i.e. opening any website) to be redirected to whatever is running on your hotspot's port 80.

Comment: So, I'll just need an Apache server running?

Comment: How do I disable this redirect?

Comment: With command: `iptables -L --line-numbers` you'll get line numbers for rules and then you can delete single line with `iptables -D nat 1` for example. 
To delete all iptables rules you can use `iptables -F`