# Client connects to node web server once connected to Raspberry Pi Access Point

Tags: web-server, node.js, access-point

I would like to connect a client to my Node.js web server via my rpi access point.

I have successfully setup my rpi3 stretch as an [access point](http://www.raspberryconnect.com/network/item/333-raspberry-pi-hotspot-access-point-dhcpcd-method). Now I am trying to have the client redirected to the simple web server running on the Pi.

I have seen this [iptables redirection](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41369/wifi-hotspot-with-redirect-to-html?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but its not working for me.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:80
```

Once my client connects to the RPi AP wifi I am not redirected to any browser to the destination of the server. I can verify the iptable rules are there using.

```
iptables -t nat -L -n -v
```

I would like to be able to have the client redirected to a browser and the destination with out having to manually open a broswer and type in the address.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: Using iptables

The Network Authentication Type didn't work for me. But redirecting using iptables did the trick. These commands found [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/41370/112713)

> ```
> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:80
> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:80
> ```
>
> This redirects all requests made via port 80 and 443 (i.e. opening any website) to be redirected to whatever is running on your hotspot's port 80.

worked when I replaced `localhost:80` with the static IP address I assigned to my raspi in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, e. g. `192.168.1.1:7070`.

---

#### Example

Maybe this might be helpful: as an example, I've set up a Node.js-server with express and added:

```
app.get('/api/ping', (req, res) => {
    return res.send('pong');
}); 

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('http://192.168.1.1:7070/api/ping');
});

app.listen(7070, '192.168.1.1');
```

Now, when a user connects to the access point using Windows 10, the browser opens up with `http://www.msftconnecttest.com/redirect` and a few seconds after that he will be redirected to `192.168.1.1:7070/api/ping`.

---

#### Option 2: Configure dnsmasq

If this still doesn't work, you could try and follow the instructions [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100118) where we specify the redirection in the DHCP server (dnsmasq).

> [...] [Y]ou can change your DNS server to redirect any request to a domain that isn't yours to the Raspberry Pi. The /etc/dnsmasq.conf file controls the DNS server. Add the following line to redirect all requests (change the IP address if you chose not to use 192.168.4.1)
>
> ```
> address=/#/192.168.1.1
> ```
>
> You will then need to set up your webserver to redirect those requests. I suggest choosing a URL, like http://mysite/, and telling your webserver (such as nginx) to show your site for that domain, and send a redirect for all other domains.

However, this only worked when I set up my server to listen to port 80 (as the websites that the OS calls to check if there is a working internet connection and to possibly redirect to a captive portal are served as HTTP). A disadvantage is that you need to run your Node.js-server with root privileges (using `sudo node yourserver.js`).

---

#### Update

Note that recently, I had to combine the two approaches to make it work as can be seen [on this interesting page](https://www.engetsu-consulting.com/blog/raspberry-pi-raspbian-rogue-access-point-ap-landing-page-captive-portal). The author creates a captive portal for an apache server but the basic setup stays the same. He states that the use of iptables is intended to "resolve all *ip addresses* to the IP address of apache2", while adding the `address=...` line in `dnsmasq.conf` is used to "to resolve all *domain names* to the IP of apache2".

Also make sure you check out sabhiram's awesome git repository [raspberry-wifi-conf](https://github.com/sabhiram/raspberry-wifi-conf), especially the [wifi_manager](https://github.com/sabhiram/raspberry-wifi-conf/blob/master/app/wifi_manager.js) if you want to turn the Rasberry Pi into an Access Point with one click. You may want to add the iptables setup to the [wifi_manager](https://github.com/sabhiram/raspberry-wifi-conf/blob/master/app/wifi_manager.js) and the `address=...` line to the [dnsmasq.ap.template](https://github.com/sabhiram/raspberry-wifi-conf/blob/master/assets/etc/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.ap.template).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can do it without using iptables by using a hostapd configuration option

```
# Network Authentication Type
# This parameter indicates what type of network authentication is used in the
# network.
# format: <network auth type indicator (1-octet hex str)> [redirect URL]
# Network Authentication Type Indicator values:
# 00 = Acceptance of terms and conditions
# 01 = On-line enrollment supported  
# 02 = http/https redirection
# 03 = DNS redirection
#network_auth_type=00
#network_auth_type=02http://www.example.com/redirect/me/here/
```

I'd set it up as

```
network_auth_type=02http://192.168.3.14:1234/url/for/node/js/stuff
```

and see what happens. I can't test it right now as none of my Raspberries are running as an access point.

https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf

Comment: looks great. ive tried adding this to my hostapd.conf file? I am going through the reference and Im unclear if i need more. my hostapd now looks like :                                                
`interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=RPiHotSpot
hw_mode=g
channel=6
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=1234567890
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP                                                                                                           network_auth_type=02http://192.168.3.14:1234/`

Comment: Don't put my example URL in there. Your IP address is probably not 192.168.3.14. And I'm 100% sure Node isn't running on port 1234.

Comment: I have changed my url to my server. Im just using your code in the example. I am using port 8001 (set from my node server) and set to my RPI IP address. I can confirm this address + port when a client and RPI are on the same wifi network. The issue seems to be this interworking disables my RPI wlan0 IP address in my setup.